Pylint protected-access (W0212) warning on module functions not class methods
I receive PylintW0212:protected-access warnings when accessing functions of a module that are prefixed with a single underscore:
import my_module
my_module._function() # Pylint warning here

The documentation for this warning says it applies "when a protected member (i.e. class member with a name beginning with an underscore) is access outside the class or a descendant of the class".  This specifically refers to classes and class members.
The highest rated questions and responses here all show examples specific to class members (example).  Is this intended behavior for modules as well as classes?
(If it is relevant, I am using the Pylint extension for VS Code.)

This is not specific to classes, and should apply to a module namespace as well. I think the Pylint explanation is just bad.
